# Are there any chemicals with this structural skeleton?

Tags: molecular-structure

Is there a chemical that has the bond structure like below?

[image]

There are 5 atoms linking together.
Two of them have 4 bonds. (They are different atoms.)
Another two of them have 3 bonds. (They can be either same or different atoms.)
The last atom has only 2 bonds.

Suggested SMILES for unknown $\ce{X}$ elements is `[X]2[X]14[X]3[X]1[X]234`

Are there such kinds of chemicals?

Comment: To clarify - does the structure have to be composed solely of carbon atoms? With no hydrogens? Or is it a saturated alkane?

Comment: The OP indicates that they can be different atoms. A compound with formula $\ce{C2B2O}$ has the correct valences to accomplish that structure, but I am unsure if it exists.

Comment: @BenNorris If it does, that is going to be one unhappy molecule, what with how far from tetrahedral that central carbon is. I suspect it would not exist for very long...

Comment: Extremely unlikely. However, if you allow ligands, a metallic cluster with this graph as part of the structure may be found.

Comment: Similar motifs include [1,1,1]propellane and white phosphorus. Neither of which is noted for its stability.

Comment: Iron(III) Triethylenetetramine complex would look like this, except that there are two carbons between the nitrogen atoms that would bind to the iron center.

Comment: Expanding on @permeakra: You may also find a gold micro-cluster somewhere. I will also check my notes on exotic boranes later.

Answer (score 14):

CCDC doesn't contain any molecules of such geometry. The closest topology observed is among pnictogens such as $\ce{P, As, Sb}$, which form tetrahedron units $[\ce{P4}]$, $[\ce{As4}]$, $[\ce{Sb4}]$ which are readily coordinating with Au, Rh, Ag and Cu by edge-sharing:

[image]

The first publication ([1](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja00351a067)) tetraphosphido-ligand presents the following structure of $\ce{Rh}$-complex:

[image]

The most relevant structure best fitting the required connectivity matrix would probably be bis(tricyclo[$1.1.0.0^{2,4}$]tetraphosphane)-gold ([2](http://pubs.rsc.org/en/Content/ArticleLanding/2012/CC/c2cc15291f)):

[image]

---

Thanks to @TAR86 comment mentioning exotic boranes, I also found a research ([3](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/anie.199721171/abstract)) on *ab initio* calculations for $\ce{B4}$ cores obtained via the following proposed reaction:

[image]

They also obtained crystal structure for bis(tetrahydropyran)-(tetra(t-butyl)tetraborane)-lithium where $\ce{B4H}$ core is present:

[image]

(1) Lindsell, W. E.; McCullough, K. J.; Welch, A. J. J. Am. Chem. Soc. 1983, 105 (13), 4487–4489. [DOI: 10.1021/ja00351a067](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja00351a067) 
(2) Forfar, L. C.; Clark, T. J.; Green, M.; Mansell, S. M.; Russell, C. A.; Sanguramath, R. A.; Slattery, J. M. Chem. Commun. 2012, 48 (14), 1970–1972. [DOI: 10.1039/C2CC15291F](http://pubs.rsc.org/en/Content/ArticleLanding/2012/CC/c2cc15291f) 
(3) Neu, A.; Mennekes, T.; Englert, U.; Paetzold, P.; Hofmann, M.; von Ragué Schleyer, P. Angew. Chem. Int. Ed. Engl. 1997, 36 (19), 2117–2119. [DOI: 10.1002/anie.199721171](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/anie.199721171/abstract)